# How to differentiate Simple past and passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, past-simple

When he saw his wife and her boyfriend chatting, he was infuriated.

In above sentence "he was infuriated" is not passive voice. It gives idea / State that he became infuriated when he saw that.

Like this can we construct below sentence in Simple past? Or this will give idea of Passive voice?

a) When the match was started?

Ans: Yes, when organiser cleared the rule, match was started.

b) Is the strike ended/Called off?

Ans: Yes, when boss declared bonus, the strike was ended/ called off.

Answer (score 1):

This premise is wrong.   The clause "he was infuriated" ***is*** in the passive voice.

That he was infuriated implies that something infuriated him.   Given the context that you've provided, we can easily guess what that something is.   He saw his wife and her boyfriend chatting.   That sight infuriated him.   He was infuriated by what he saw.

> The match was started.   -- a passive-voice past-tense statement
>   When was the match started?   -- a passive-voice past-tense question
>   The strike is ended.   -- a passive-voice present-tense statement
>   Is the strike ended?   -- a passive-voice present-tense question

Some verbs are [ergative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb).   The verbs *to start* and *to end* happen to be two examples.   In a passive-voice construction they imply that some semantic actor or agent exists, even when no such agent is specified or even suggested.   In an active-voice construction that has no direct object, they do something different:

> The match started.
>   Did the match start?
>   The strike ends today.
>   Does the strike end today?

These examples use the same grammatical forms and structures as ordinary active-voice clauses.   However, they have the kind of meaning that in some other languages is expressed in [the middle voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Middle).

The verb *to infuriate* is not ergative.   The statement "he infuriated", in the active voice and without direct object, simply doesn't make sense.   Statements that do make sense include the clearly active "something infuriated him" and the clearly passive "he was infuriated".

Answer (score 0):

Because your example questions are past tense, they require the past form of *do* used as an *auxiliary verb*:

> When **did** the match start?
>
> **Did** the strike end?

Here is an excellent page that describes how to use *do/does/did* as an auxiliary verb to construct questions: http://www.grammar.cl/english/do-does-did-done.htm

***Called off*** is actually passive voice, so you can say either of the following:

> Is the strike called off?
>
> **Did** the strike **get** called off?